# MySqlx xDevApi driver CDK Error: Connection refused (generic:111) mysql-connector-c++

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector-c

I am facing this random issue when connecting mysqlx over 33060 port on container. mysql-connector-c++ give error that  CDK Error: Connection refused (generic:111). Usually what happens is it get connected when the container is spawned first time but when i stop the service/process it gives the connection refused.

Not sure if the connection/session are not purged after i kill the process or port/socket is chocked.

Comment: do you used mysql from docker ?

Comment: Yes, faced this issue once again, it got resolved automatically some how and it reappeared for no reason :S